# Application rejected on Google Play two times

Tags: android, google-play

It's my first App **`"Food Network Cuisine"`**. This application is based on **API**, it is getting all its context from a websites that its main job is reviewing foods recipes.
 The app version got rejected from Google Play, **REASON FOR REJECTION: Thanks for submitting your app to Google Play. I reviewed Food Network Cuisine, your app title violates our impersonation policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.**

This **title** which I have chosen is unique, I don't have any idea about this problem. Do you have any solution for this issue.

**Logo is designed by me:**

[image]

Did anybody have this problem with an update on google play? Is there any way around it maybe? Or can somebody show me how I can avoid this problem?

Comment: do you have the permission of that website to use their api?

Comment: Please try to change the name of it..This is the issue

Comment: Do you have on your account another app with the same name? maybe another version not published previously loaded on the store. Does it exist another app with the same package name?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: have you read [this](https://play.google.com/about/ip-deception-spam/)

Comment: yes this API have permission, the problem is the title, when you search about it, you won't find any app with the same title as mine !! It's weird

Comment: no It's my first Application in android play store

Comment: What about the app icon and graphics? Are they your own creations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because even though your app name is unique in itself, it uses the words **Food Network** which is a big brand in a food domain. They are also one of Google Play Store's top developers. You probably need to change the title of your app.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will change completely the title

Comment: If that works for you, please be kind to mark this as the right answer. Best of luck :)

Comment: I changed completely the Title and I succeeded to publish my App, Many Thanks.